# How to resolve this error "Array element can not be nil"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Below code generates error

> Array element can not be nil

when I assign the value in `aryResult[0]`

```
NSMutableArray *tempResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
switch (habitObj.NoOfTimesPer)
{
    case 1://NO_OF_TIMES_PER_DAY
    {
        tempResult = [self getTotalNoOfDaysOrWeeks_createdDate:habitObj.strCreatedDt totalsOf:@"TOTAL_DAYS"];
    }
        break;
    case 2://NO_OF_TIMES_PER_WEEK
    {
        tempResult = [self getTotalNoOfDaysOrWeeks_createdDate:habitObj.strCreatedDt totalsOf:@"TOTAL_WEEKS"];
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
aryResult[0]    = tempResult[0];
aryResult[3]    = tempResult[1];
```

The code below does not generate error:

```
[tempResult addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
[tempResult addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
aryResult[0]    = tempResult[0];
aryResult[3]    = tempResult[1];
```

Comment: make a mutalble copy of that array don't assign directly in if else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method

`[self getTotalNoOfDaysOrWeeks_createdDate:habitObj.strCreatedDt totalsOf:@"TOTAL_DAYS"];`

returns `nil`, so `tempResult` becomes `nil` after assignment inside the `switch` statement.

Calling `tempResult[0]` is a shorthand for `[tempResult objectAtIndex:0]`. And it returns `nil`, because in Objective-C a method called on `nil` object always returns `nil`. Then you try to add `nil` object to `NSMutableArray`, which is not allowed, so the app crashes.